# Does xCode's iPhone simulator become unresponsive if the computer's date is wrong?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

For whatever reason, my laptop reverted its date to something in 2001. I tried running my code in XCode, but it ran an older version of the code, no matter how many times I updated it. However, after I adjusted the date, the code ran fine. Is there a reason that the simulator doesn't work with wrong dates?

Comment: Have u tried running the same code on iOS device(may be iPhone/iPad)? Let us know if u encounter the same problem. U said "It ran older version of code", but it must be in your hand which version u want to run unless it is not coupled with system date!